# Unexpected token "<variable declaration>" was found following ""

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

Im a newbie to DB2. Im trying to convert this sp from Microsoft SQL server to DB2
Here is the sp from Microsoft SQL:

```
    DECLARE @DELIMITER VARCHAR(1) =','
    DECLARE  @FILTER_TYPE VARCHAR(128) ='Animal_ID_17'
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp_Inputs
    CREATE TABLE #tmp_Inputs
    (
     INPUT_VALUE VARCHAR(128)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmp_Inputs(INPUT_VALUE)
    SELECT COL1 FROM [dbo].[fn_Split_String](@INPUT_VALUE,@DELIMITER)


    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp_Animals
    CREATE TABLE #tmp_Animals
    (
     ANIMAL_ID VARCHAR(128)
    )

    IF @FILTER_TYPE ='Animal_Id_17'
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO #tmp_Animals
       (
           ANIMAL_ID
       )
       SELECT a.ANIMAL_ID
       FROM #tmp_Inputs t
       INNER JOIN ANIMALS a ON t.INPUT_VALUE = a.ANIMAL_ID
    END 

    SELECT * FROM #tmp_Animals
    ORDER BY ANIMAL_ID
```

and this is the sp after i converted to DB2

```
DECLARE @FILTER_TYPE VARCHAR(128);
    SET @FILTER_TYPE = 'Animal_ID_17';
    DECLARE @DELIMITER VARCHAR(3);
    SET @DELIMITER = ',';

    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Input_EMP
    (   
        INPUT_VALUE VARCHAR(128)

    );

    INSERT INTO Input_EMP(INPUT_VALUE)
    SELECT COL1 FROM fn_Split_String @INPUT_VALUE,@DELIMITER;

    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Animals_EMP
    (
        ANIMAL_ID VARCHAR(128)
    );

    IF @FILTER_TYPE ='Animal_Id_17' THEN
        INSERT INTO Animals_EMP
        (
            ANIMAL_ID
        )
        SELECT a.ANIMAL_ID
        FROM Input_EMP a
        JOIN ANIMALS n on a.INPUT_VALUE = n.ANIMAL_ID;
    END IF;

    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN for

    SELECT ANIMAL_ID
    FROM Animals_EMP
    ORDER BY ANIMAL_ID;

    OPEN cursor1;
```

Then i got this error:
**An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56**

Does anyone know how to resolved this error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db2 [compound SQL statements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html) that comprise bodies of stored procedures require that `DECLARE` statements precede any executable statements and follow a well defined order, as shown in the linked documentation. In your code they are scattered all over the place, which is what the error message is trying to tell you.